# Console output broken in MSYS2 - unaligned lines after pasting with `Shift-Ins`

Tags: shell, console, mingw, msys2, msys

After I paste anything on  MSYS2 console using `Shift-Ins`, my output of `ls` on console looks messy like this:

[image]

I tried to press `CTRL-L` or type `clear` command, does not help.

I use MSYS2 under Windows 10.

Comment: Does restoring the terminal settings with `stty sane` work?

Comment: @ssbssa thank you! It is interesting, but I cannot reproduce the behaviour any more! And I didn't restart the computer, I just tried it again after 3 days. Strange, because it was doing it all the time 3 days ago, even when I restarted the app.